# Struts2 Interceptor Conversion Error

Tags: struts2, passwords, interceptor, sha256

I am trying to update a form where user information is diplayed  which has password field.
Password is SHA256 format,When I Submit the form
Struts2 throws the below error
**InterceptorMapping: [conversionError] => [org.apache.struts2.interceptor.StrutsConversionErrorInterceptor]**

In case the password is not SHA256 it works all well.
Any inputs why struts2 interceptor can not understand sha256 ?

Comment: New observation If string starts with character '{ 'then this issue occurs any inputs

Answer (score 0):

Problem Resolved there was one interceptor which whitelisted some special chars and since sha256 includes { character which was not included in the list and hence the exception